# Divs inside span keep collapsing on each other

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

Here is the link to the webpage I am building:

https://aa21fdc571424e82b426191b66978480.codepen.website

The problem I can't seem to solve has to do with the three achievements that are underneath the paragraph of text. These three achievements are each in their own div, wrapped in a span.

```
<section class="achievement_wrapper">
   <div class ="achievement" id="achievement1"><p class="achievement_text">Achievement 1</p></div>
   <div class ="achievement" id="achievement2"><p class="achievement_text">Achievement 2</p></div>
<div class ="achievement" id="achievement3"><p class="achievement_text">Self-Authoring Suite</p></div>
</section>
```

When I decrease browser width, I would like for them to collapse into a column when the size makes it necessary. For some reason though, I can't get it to happen no matter what I seem to try. The current wrapper class code:

```
.achievement_wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row-wrap;
    align-items: flex-end;   
}
```

Or perhaps it's something with specificity that is messing the whole thing up?

[image: The Problem]

I would like these to move out onto separate rows when they run out of space.

Comment: Make sure there is no space in `class="`. Also, I see no span in the code you show here. Only a section wrapping the divs.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have a media query, but you have a sintax error

> For big screens

```
@media screen and (min-width: 450px){
.achievement_wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

> For small screens

```
@media screen and (max-width: 449px){
.achievement_wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

Using the `row` and `column` values, will give your desired result.

It is recomended to have a mobile first approach. So you should only have one media querie and a default-mobile style. So your code shpould look like this:

```
.achievement_wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 450px){
.achievement_wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    align-items: flex-end;
    }

}
```

Hope this is what you were looking for. Happy to explain or help in a better solution if needed.

Comment: Mobile works fine. My problem happens between 451px-900px(ish). Instead of having a minimum margin between achievements, they move together into one big mess. I'll edit and add in a pic of what I mean.